# why no implicit conversion from pointer to reference to const pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, const-correctness

I'll illustrate my question with code:

```
#include <iostream>

void PrintInt(const unsigned char*& ptr)
{
    int data = 0;
    ::memcpy(&data, ptr, sizeof(data));
    // advance the pointer reference.
    ptr += sizeof(data);
    std::cout << std::hex << data << " " << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    unsigned char buffer[] = { 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, };

    /* const */ unsigned char* ptr = buffer;

    PrintInt(ptr);  // error C2664: ...
    PrintInt(ptr);  // error C2664: ...    

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code (in VS2008) I get this: error C2664: 'PrintInt' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned char *' to 'const unsigned char *&'. If I uncomment the "const" comment it works fine.

However shouldn't pointer implicitly convert into const pointer and then reference be taken? Am I wrong in expecting this to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the pointer gets converted to a const pointer, as you suggest, then the result of that conversion is a temporary value, an *rvalue*. You cannot attach a non-const reference to an rvalue - it is illegal in C++.

For example, this code will not compile for a similar reason

```
int i = 42;
double &r = i;
```

Even though type `int` is convertible to type `double`, it still doesn't mean that you can attach a `double &` reference to the result of that conversion.

However, a const reference (i.e. a reference of reference-to-const type) can be attached to an rvalue, meaning that this code will compile perfectly fine

```
int i = 42;
const double &r = i;
```

In your case if you declare your function as

```
void PrintInt(const unsigned char* const& ptr) // note the extra `const`
```

the code will compile.

Comment: Yeah, what he said :) function signature needs a const reference: though passing pointers by reference is a bit pointless since pointers and references need to be the same size anyway...

Comment: That's not correct. References are more likely to be zero size than the same size as pointers.

Answer (score 8):

That will break the const-correctness:

```
// if it was allowed
const int x = 5;
int *p;
const int*& cp = p; // cp is a ´constant´ alias to p
cp = &x;            // make cp (and p) point to a constant
*p = 7;             // !!!!
```

If the conversion was allowed the above code would compile. Once you have initialized `cp` with `p` (forbidden in the language) they are aliases. Now you can use `cp` to point to any constant object, since it is a pointer to a *constant* object. Modifying the value pointed by `p` is also valid code, since it is a pointer to a non-const object, but since `p` and `cp` are the same it would be modifying a constant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

`void PrintInt(const unsigned char* const& ptr)`

if you want to pass a const pointer by reference.

Comment: What is the point of passing a pointer by reference-to-const? Why not just pass the pointer by value?

Comment: @Fred Exactly, I wouldn't bother; see my comment @AndreyT :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert a reference to a pointer because the pointer can be null and a reference can't. In other words the reference is more restrictive that a pointer. A reference is always a valid pointer but the opposite is not always true.