# Why does this conversion from int to double& not work?

Tags: c++, reference

Error!

```
$ cat double.cc
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    int i = 42;
    double &r = i;
}
$ g++ double.cc
double.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
double.cc:5: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘double&’
from expression of type ‘int’
$
```

Works!

```
$ cat double.cc
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    int i = 42;
    const double &r = i;
}
$ g++ double.cc
$
```

Why do we get the error in the first case? I know this is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908244), but I am not sure I understand why this not allowed, while `int` to `const double&` is allowed?

Comment: Why the random driveby downvote with no comment? This is a good question, particularly so since Moeb researched it and found a related question whose answer was (at least to Moeb) not quite satisfactory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write

```
int i = 42;
double const &r = i;
```

`i` is implicitly converted to a double, which results in a temporary value, or *rvalue*. A non-const reference is not allowed to bind to an rvalue, so `r` needs to be a `double const&` for the above to work.

Answer (score 6):

```
int i = 42;
double &r = i;
```

Here `r` is a reference to `double`, but `i` is not a `double`, then how can `r` refer to it? It cannot. So it creates a temporary object of type `double` out of the expression `i`. But again, `r` which is *non-const* reference, cannot bind to a temporary object.

However, if you make it const reference, then it would work:

```
double const & r = i;
```

Note that `const` reference can bind to a temporary object which is created out of `i`.

Comment: But then, how can `const double&` refer to an `int`?

Comment: @Moeb: Edited and Explained.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

In C++ you can almost think of references as alias to another variable. They must match in non-cv qualified type, and in this case the types are different.

The reason it works with `const double&` is becaused the compiler creates a temporary `double` with a copy of `i`'s value and binds the const reference to that temporary. This is allowed because binding to a temporary extends the life of the temporary to the lifetime of the reference.